# REACTJS render method not updating after state update

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Hey guys i have a basic object which looks like this:
[image: PIC1]

Now i want to add an element to "options" and those should render a new JSX element like this:
[image: PIC2]

This is my "add" function:
[image: PIC3]

The state is getting updated but there will no new JSX be rendered.
Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let tmpExtraObject = extraObject
```

This doesn't copy the object, so any changes you do to it afterwards are mutating the original object. Then when you set state with that same object, react will do a `===` between the old and new state, see that they're the same object, and so skip rendering.

Instead, you need to create a copy of your state and change the copy:

```
let tmpExtraObject = {
   ...extraObject,
   options: [
      ...extraObject.options,
      {
        id: extraObject.options.length + 1,
        name: "",
        priceBase: "",
        isDefault: false,
      }
   ];
}
setExtraObject(tmpExtraObject)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I thought "let tmpExtraObject = extraObject" is doing the copy... 
You are my hero!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete `value :`  :

```
setExtraObject({
id:...,
options :...
})
```

Copy your state in your add function instead of defining a new variable that points to it  :

```
const tmpExtraObject = {...extraObject}
```